# Unwrapping the UILabel error while implementing Delegate and Protocols

Tags: ios, swift

Here I am getting error when unwrapping the del UIlabel

`@IBOutlet weak var del: UILabel!` // my label must change through protocol implementation

`del.text = name` // error here

> Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value

**ViewController.swift**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController,DataPass {

    @IBOutlet weak var del: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    @IBAction func seconeView(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let selview = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SecondViewController")as!SecondViewController
        present(selview,animated: true,completion: nil)

    }

    func pass(name: String) {
            del.text = name // error here Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value
    }
}
```

**SecondViewController.swift**

```
protocol DataPass {
    func pass(name:String)
}
class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

    let delegate:DataPass! = ViewController()
    let label = "Delegate"
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }


    @IBAction func endView(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if let del = delegate {
                del.pass(name: label)
        } else {
            print("Delegate property is not set")
        }
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: Wire the label outlet with the control shown in the interface builder.

Comment: @ElTomato it is already wired

Comment: You can create extension of ViewController with `DataPass` delegate and put the `pass` function in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few changes you need to do to make your `delegate` working:

In second controller make these changes:

```
protocol DataPass {
    func pass(name:String)
}

class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

    var delegate:DataPass?
    let label = "Delegate"
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    @IBAction func endView(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if let del = delegate {
            del.pass(name: label)
        } else {
            print("Delegate property is not set")
        }
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

}
```

and in first controller :

```
class ViewController: UIViewController,DataPass {

    @IBOutlet weak var del: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    @IBAction func seconeView(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let selview = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SecondViewController")as!SecondViewController
        selview.delegate = self
        present(selview,animated: true,completion: nil)
    }

    func pass(name: String) {
          del.text = name 
    }
}
```

**Explanation:**

In this line `let delegate:DataPass! = ViewController()` you are creating `another instance` for your delegate variable which doesn't hold any label. You need to assign your `ViewController's instance` while presenting the next controller to make it working.